# Употребление предлога с аббревиатурой

Tags: предлоги, аббревиатуры

Предположим: **ПХК** = Пермский хлебокомбинат.
Как правильно написать: *нарушения **на** ПХК* или *нарушения **в** ПХК*?

Answer (score 2):

Согласование по главному слову в аббревиатуре. На комбинат, на комбинате.

См. похожий вопрос к Справке Грамоты.ру:

[Вопрос № 297084](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=297084)

> Добрый день! Подскажите, как правильно употреблять предлоги: «Иванов
>   А. Е. работает на (или в/во) ФГУП «Атом» с 2012 года».

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Возможны варианты: *работает во ФГУП* (в организации), *работает на
>   ФГУП* (на предприятии).